# FFMPEG creating hls segments with equal length in audio and video

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, audio-streaming

Im trying to create segments (.m4s) out of an .mp4 file for an hls stream. In order to later play the segments in any order I want the segments to be equal in video and audio  duration.

I was playing around for quite a while and did the segmentation with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -hls_time 1.000 -hls_segment_type fmp4 -vcodec libx264 -hls_flags 
independent_segments -flags +cgop -g 30 -hls_playlist_type event new/output.m3u8
```

But if I have a look at the segments using `mp4dump` the duration of the streams differ by quite a lot.

```
[styp] size=8+16
[sidx] size=12+40, version=1
  reference_ID = 1
  timescale = 15360
  earliest_presentation_time = 16384
  first_offset = 52
[sidx] size=12+40, version=1
  reference_ID = 2
  timescale = 44100
  earliest_presentation_time = 44924
  first_offset = 0
[moof] size=8+584
  [mfhd] size=12+4
    sequence number = 2
  [traf] size=8+312
    [tfhd] size=12+16, flags=20038
      track ID = 1
      default sample duration = 512
      default sample size = 1739
      default sample flags = 1010000
    [tfdt] size=12+8, version=1
      base media decode time = 15360
    [trun] size=12+252, flags=a05
      sample count = 30
      data offset = 600
      first sample flags = 2000000
  [traf] size=8+240
    [tfhd] size=12+16, flags=20038
      track ID = 2
      default sample duration = 1024
      default sample size = 477
      default sample flags = 2000000
    [tfdt] size=12+8, version=1
      base media decode time = 43008
    [trun] size=12+180, flags=201
      sample count = 43
      data offset = 4750
      [mdat] size=8+21769
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Your video segment is 30 frames at 30 frames per second - so it is about 1 second.
Your audio segment is 43 samples with 1024 length which is 44032. Which comes out to 0.998 seconds at your 44100 kHz sample rate.

I'd say your audio and video segment length is within 1 ms.

Comment: Thanks for your input. So basically there was no issue, just me not being able to read the output properly. So Thanks a lot!